# Cross-validation score

Tags: data-science, data-analysis

can a **Mean Square Error** be negative in Cross-Validation ? if not then, what below code is trying to say

```
-1 * cross_val_score(lre,x_data[['horsepower']], y_data,cv=4,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mean square error can not be negative, it returns a value greater than zero and values closer to zero are better.
The code scoring='neg_mean_squared_error' asking to return negative scoring which means that values closer to zero are worse, then you multiply the result by -1